# How to get the input value of an input on which a function is being called in angularjs? (Directive, ng-repeat)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

how do I get a value of an input that is in ng-repeat? I want to be able to **ng-repeat the value** (as a default) but I also want **to be able to change the value**.

It's hard to explain what I mean but I can give you can example:

In my Directive (the relevant part):

```
ctrl.numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]

ctrl.myFun = function () {
    console.log(ctrl.val)
};
```

My HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="num in numbers">
    <input type="text" value="{{num}}" ng-click="ctrl.myFun()">
</div>
```

So on click I want to get the "this" value of the input on which the function is being called. I thought this will be supereasy but every way I try to do it I get **undefined**. I tried to do it with `scope { value : "@" }` inside my directive and failed, I tried ng-model and ng-bind and failed as well.

I want to be able to attach the function to multiple fields so I don't want to hardcode any variables.

Many thanks!

Comment: This is an angular app. Use ng-model.

Comment: How exaclty? How do I print the value and get it at the same time? How do I avoid the problem that when I change one value inside my ng-repeat that all other ng-repeat inputs get the same value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, use ng-model because it's Angular and just pass the value to the function like so.

```
<div ng-repeat="num in numbers">
    <input type="text" ng-model="num" ng-click="ctrl.myFun(num)">
</div>

ctrl.numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]

ctrl.myFun = function (val) {
    console.log(val)
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w66e45r8/)